# Spring boot: @Repository class not found to inject

Tags: spring-boot

This is my Spring boot application related code:

```
@ComponentScan({"net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.scheduler", "net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.backoffice"})
public class SchedulerApplication {//...}
```

By other hand, I've a repository on package `net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.backoffice.dao`:

```
@Repository
public interface DocumentDAO extends CrudRepository<Document, String> {

}
```

So, I've a service with a `DocumentDAO` dependency:

```
@Service
public class DocumentServiceBackOffice {

    private DocumentDAO documentDAO;

    public DocumentServiceBackOffice(DocumentDAO documentDAO) {
                this.documentDAO = documentDAO;
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting this message:

> NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.backoffice.dao.DocumentDAO' available

I've also tried adding `@EnableJpaRepositories`, but it still doesn't work.

Any ideas?

**EDIT**

This is my `SpringApplication` class:

```
package net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc;

import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.jmx.JmxAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.boot.context.properties.EnableConfigurationProperties;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Import;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.config.EnableJpaRepositories;
import org.springframework.scheduling.annotation.EnableScheduling;

import net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.common.config.FrontOfficeProperties;
import net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.common.config.RedisConfiguration;

@SpringBootApplication(exclude = JmxAutoConfiguration.class)
@EnableConfigurationProperties({
    FrontOfficeProperties.class
})
@Import(RedisConfiguration.class)
@EnableScheduling
// @ComponentScan("net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc")
//@EnableJpaRepositories
public class SchedulerApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(SchedulerApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

**EDIT2:**

I've just realized on spring logs that there's some issue related with `DocumentDAO`:

> --- [           main] .RepositoryConfigurationExtensionSupport : Spring Data JPA - Could not safely identify store assignment for repository candidate interface net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.backoffice.dao.DocumentDAO.

Comment: Remove the annotations, leave only `@SpringBootApplication` and place the class annotated with that in the `net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc` package and not in some sub package. This is also the suggested way by the Spring Boot Team.

Comment: Wow... Ive tried it and it's still failing... It's really strange, isn't it?

Comment: Add your full `@SpringBootApplication` annotated class.

Comment: I've just added that on post.

Comment: You've cleaned and rebuild everything with the new class?

Comment: I've just realized spring logs is telling something about repository but I don't quite figure out what's wrong... I've edited post.

Comment: You are using both Redis and Jpa in your application. The repository can be used for either one. You can try using `JpaRepository` instead of `CrudRepository` or disable JPA or Redis Repository detection.

Answer (score 1):

Try adding the following:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages="net.gencat.transversal.espaidoc.backoffice.dao")
public class SchedulerApplication
```